# Issue with scaling width of background-image (CSS)

Tags: image, css, width, scaling, image-scaling

I'm havig troubles with an image that, by using "contain" in CSS adds a huge spacing between the top image and the next paragraph. When i use "cover" there is no spacing issue but the pictures width is too high.

I'm using this in CSS

```
.headerLine{
position: relative;
width: 100%;
overflow: hidden;
height: auto;
background-repeat: no-repeat;
background-position: center top;
background-image: url(../images/bgTop.jpg);
-webkit-background-size: cover;
-moz-background-size: cover;
-o-background-size: cover;
background-size: contain;
```

I upoaded pictures for 100% Desktop, using Cover, using contain and one for the wished results here: [Description](https://i.stack.imgur.com/OV3hQ.jpg)

Answer (score 0):

Have you considered including the image as an `<img>` instead of as a background image? This will cause the headerLine div to dynamically change height to match the child image.

HTML:

```
<div class="headerLine">
    <img src="sampleimg.jpg" alt="Sample Image" width="600" height="200">
</div>
```

CSS:

```
.headerLine img {
    display: block;
    width: 100%;
    height: auto;
}
```

Concerning background size from W3 Schools:

Background Cover:

> Scale the background image to be as large as possible so that the
>   background area is completely covered by the background image. Some
>   parts of the background image may not be in view within the background
>   positioning area Background cover will scale the image

Background Contain:

> Scale the image to the largest size such that both its width and its
>   height can fit inside the content area